# Using IAuthenticate with a Web Browser - Unwanted cached credentials

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, authentication, webbrowser-control

I am using IAuthenticate, IServiceProvider and IOleClientSite in order to open my web browser control and pass the credentials of the login.

(I have a form that contains a web browser control, my form implements the above interfaces)

Everything is working great - when I call a webpage with my form passing the credentials, the webpage opens with the proper credentials. The problem is: if I make two consecutive calls (each with different credentials), only the first credential set is used (first credentials are used in both calls and second credentials are being ignored).

Any clue on how to force the Credentials for the IAuthenticate implementation? is it caching somewhere? Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InternetSetOption(NULL, INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION) will reset the current session. Note this is a process wide operation, not only affect your webbrowser control but other webbrowser control and any WinInet operation.

See also: Microsoft Knowledge base article q195192 [How To Clear Logon Credentials to Force Reauthentication](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/195192).

Comment: Sadly, this is now a broken link.